# oracle sql optimization

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance, sql-optimization

I have this query:

```
SELECT sd.sdt_service_type,
       sd.sdt_status,
       count(*) col_count
FROM mci_service_data sd
WHERE
     sd.sdt_version = 1
     AND sd.sdt_type = 'MMSP'
     AND sd.sdt_status in (?)
     AND(sd.STD_OPERATION_FLAG is null OR sd.STD_OPERATION_FLAG not like 'mark%')
     AND sd.sdt_office_id in
     (SELECT op.fld_ofs_id
      FROM mci_ofs_per op
      WHERE op.fld_per_id = ?)
group by sd.sdt_service_type,sd.sdt_status
```

in mci_service_data table there are indexes on 
`mci_service_data(sdt_type, sdt_version, sdt_status, sdt_office_id)`
 and `mci_ofs_per(fld_per_id, fld_ofs_id)`.but this query takes time more than 10 seconds!

So,how this query will be optimize and faster?

Comment: Why `sd.sdt_status in (?)` rather than `sd.sdt_status = ?`? (If you are supplying a comma-separated string to the bind variable then that will not work as it will still be treated as a single string not multiple values.)

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statement for the table in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan for your query. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: how much data there are i the 2 tables ? can you show us query plan? and what do you mean by (?) ? the data are changing a lot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this query, I would recommend the following indexes:

- `mci_service_data(sdt_type, sdt_version, sdt_status, sdt_office_id)`
- `mci_ofs_per(fld_per_id, fld_ofs_id)`

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff, but the tables have that indexes.

Comment: @Saeed.Satari . . . That is *two* indexes, one with four  columns and one with two columns.  Those are not the indexes you have described in the question.